# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type when try to index an object type

Tags: typescript, indexing

Defining the type as follows will not throw a typescript error
This is not good because the code at line 22 can attempt to set a key that does not exist.

```
// type Lane = 
//  {
//    [key: string]: string | number | null;
//  }
```

I guess it is better to have a more specific type definition so that
typescript will throw an error if the code attempts to set a key that does not exist.
Defining the type as follows will throw the typescript compile error

> /* Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type 'Lane'.   No index signature with
> a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Lane' */

but this error appears even when attempting to set a key that does in fact exist.

```
 type Lane = 
 {
   firstname: string,
   age: number,
   hairColor: string
 }
```

How can I define my type with specific keys, but still be able to index an object of this type with a string?

```
const lane: Lane = {
  firstname: 'Bob',
  age: 30,
  hairColor: 'Blue'
}

const columnId: string = 'lastname';

lane[columnId] = 'Smith';
/* Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Lane'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Lane' */

console.log('lane: ' + JSON.stringify(lane));
```

One thought I had for achieving the desired outcome of enforcing the specific type without compile errors is to wrap the line that sets the value in a conditional like...

```
const laneKeys = (Object.keys(lane) as Array<keyof Lane>)
if (laneKeys.includes(columnId))
lane[columnId] = 'Smith';
```

However, this throws the error

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'keyof Lane'

I think I'm getting closer if I do the following...

```
 type laneKeys = keyof Lane;
    lane[columnId as laneKeys] = 'Smith';
```

But that approach throws this error...

> Type 'string | number | null' is not assignable to type 'null'.   Type
> 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'

This example formatted nicely in Typescript playground can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEFMDMEsDsEHNQBcAWk0E8AOWBDAZ1GgHsAbCsgdxJtitHjNTXQCdbQCd8iAxh1i42kDlw4AoEKAAq6WCSXNWoJGTIATUACNIAggFciWDFgHbCbCgiwAmAByhD8HqlSQAtqLRlQpmy8ANaQ2OwEbFpkkCQsYgAeSqgAdFKoeFgAMgTwWAC8oFKgoADexSWgANqh2ABcAajC8EgAug1ETcigAD7MRl76HL39VADcFQC%20UjJgAJLqRrHKbCr6HuJ%20oOgEAG6EoF5kHFhE%20AKwcAJ8WFowCLCosGRuRP4YkbM3gsK%20DEwYLg0HhucSSUCXdgWKzuTw%20VAkVD%20QI8UC1CJRGJxNSQJKdNKyKBwRAtKE3HgkchUWj0RgUdhA1EZfhCERsSw%20RhYMHHdygWx5UBOAA0X10RjYGBUPOGBFw%20AIHBIkH2bhomDckThom6SICkCCaLCGNA0ViELc0AIAkSyTSX2Z2VyBSKsnKshKcCVqHgBC8kA6XRaoo9PCQAf6g3EIbAJR2sA4AGFKMdA80kF9plJLPBOvznQ0coLCuVPQnOr7-Q0AOQAITIumropKBHDDQAzAAGZvbAgJ5PUDg12sUJbVqRZnN5yyjrzwOZaNPdQrVijEH1%20yDViZSNd5KozgbzrStUArgDKXke6G3MgAVKAAKIUbyQeCrHy2C6oCjhHYkXJQGrXJsGrcl9EMExuQSXATiIIhnjcMhoHJatOnTMDXGrNh9FAKCdD1BA7gSVCiy3NISgAOX8IjcQCWAkF9VAjBOUAGAwVFcEVTdPGGZDUPQ5AwJoYhSDIIx4B0F5SOdMC72AGYp0oSAUmoJAAApVwLIDQAAalAAApc8AHlKJSQSWkubB1L3SAAEo7ImIA)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following declaration. It would allow new properties as you go but keep enforcing the type for the explicit declared properties.

```js
type Lane = Record<string, string | number | null> & {
  firstname: string,
  age: number,
  hairColor: string
}
```